# What is the meaning of writing a field outside of the constructor of a class?

Tags: javascript, properties, field

I'm just finished watch a video that talking about a new feature that will enable js to support private field and methods.
The video tried to explain the difference between field and properties.
The way i understand if it is inside the  class but not inside the constructor it is a field, but inside the constructor it is a property. **But** i can't understand  what is  the difference.
For example:

```
  class Account {
  locale = navigator.language;   //public **field**
  #movements = [];            //private **field**
  #pin;                       //private **field**

  constructor(owner, currency, pin) {
    this.owner = owner;          //**property**
    this.currency = currency;   //**property**
    this.#pin = pin;


    console.log(`Thanks for opening an account, ${owner}`);
  }


  getMovements() {
    return this.#movements;
  }

  deposit(val) {
    this.#movements.push(val);
    return this;
  }

  withdraw(val) {
    this.deposit(-val);
    return this;
  }
}
```

What is the difference between **locale, movements and pin** to **owner and currency**?

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields

Comment: One not-obvious difference: by explicitly declaring public and private fields as part of the class, and not just as code in the constructor, the runtime can potentially optimize allocation of instances because it knows their "shape". (This example is not particularly good, as it uses both approaches to initializing instance properties.)

Answer (score 2):

A public field is the same thing as a normal property. No difference other than syntax.

A private field *must* be declared in the class definition (outside of the `constructor`), it cannot be created by assignment.

All field initialisations (i.e. what you put after the `=`) are implicitly moved into the constructor, to run immediately when the instance is constructed.

```
class Account {
  locale = navigator.language; // public field with initialisation
  #movements = [];             // private field with initialisation
  #pin;                        // private field

  constructor(owner, currency, pin) {
    this.owner = owner;        // property creation by assignment
    this.currency = currency;  // property creation by assignment
    this.#pin = pin;           // assignment


    console.log(`Thanks for opening an account, ${owner}`);
  }
}
```

is the same as

```
class Account {
  #movements;
  #pin;

  constructor(owner, currency, pin) {
    this.locale = navigator.language;
    this.#movements = [];
    this.#pin = undefined;

    this.owner = owner;
    this.currency = currency;
    this.#pin = pin;


    console.log(`Thanks for opening an account, ${owner}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my understanding of it all,

When you say fields, properties etc you basically mean the same thing i.e. the variable's which are allocated memory whenever you create an instance of the class.

However to instantiate or to create an instance of the Class you might have to have some properties for that new object

eg: imagine a `Person` class,

```
class Person {
   country = "USA"
   constructor(age, name) {
     this.age = age;
     this.name = name;
   }
}

let newPerson = new Person(18, "John");
```

for arguments sake let's consider every person is from USA, hence we just create a property called country and just give it a default value of "USA"

so for every new object created it will have properties: age, name and country.
they can be accessed by

```
newPerson.age
newPerson.name
newPerson.country
```

these basically can be referred to as variables/properties etc
But javascript not being like a traditional OO language in its attempt to make ammends is introducing private variables in a class, the reason being

imagine for the person class you want to have additional logic i.e. a method that outputs if the person is adult or not, normally you'll create a method and check if `this.age >= 18` and output accordingly, but for arguments sake we'll create another variable to store if the person is adult or not

let's make it a boolean and just default it to true (again, its all bad design but we'll just do it for experimenting)

```
class Person {
   country = "USA"
   #isAdult = true

   constructor(age, name) {
     this.age = age;
     this.name = name;
   }

   isPersonAdult() {
      if(this.#isAdult) return `${this.name} is an adult`
      else `${this.name} is not an adult`
   }
}

let newPerson = new Person(18, "John");
```

we have not handled logic to check if he is actually an adult

normally without the # symbol (indicating private) we could've accessed the boolean using `newPerson.isAdult`, however our hypothetical design just does not want to expose the variable, because it's just as easy to change if false if it's accessible, hence this variable whose primary purpose is our internal implementation use and does not necessarily define the person can be called as a field

so to sum it all don't get confused in semantics and the difference between
the variable's defiled in constructor and outside are:

you need to set some things whenever the class is instantiated, those settings are provided during instantiation as `new Person(18, "John")` but the class is much more than just the one's provided.
so we create our own variables, and can place it anywhere and initialize it however we want and maybe we want to set it's value depending upon what is provided and not directly ask the the variable to be provided, like we can handle our #isAdult varible

```
   constructor(age, name) {
     this.age = age;
     this.name = name;
     if( age < 18 ) {
        this.#isAdult = false;
     }
   }
```

nobody should care how we determine if person is an adult just care that there is a method which outputs if its an adult or not, hence mark the variable private and handle our own logic in class

Comment: thanks for the great and impressive explanation